# Full screen on Android with different Resolutions for 2D Game

Tags: java, android, resolution

Here's my issue. If I program a game to take up the screen size, for example, 640x480 it will work fine on a 640x480 device. However when it's played on a larger device (ex: tablet) 1280x960 the game will only be in the top left corner.

I know I could make the game check the screen size and then use different DPI sprites using a switch statement and have tons of multiplications applied to the x,y coordinates of the sprites, however there has to be a better way. I'm already dedicating a large amount of power to sprite plotting which is ridiculous.

How do I account for this to ensure my game will work on a veriety of Android Devices?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure with this one but you could try. Add this in your manifest just after the  /> tag.

```
   <support-screens
       android:xlargeScreens="true"
       android:largeScreens="true"
       android:normalScreens="true"
       android:smallScreens="true"
   />
```

Comment: sorry about that. add it up after the <uses-sdk> tag.

Comment: To clarify, I am drawing sprites using a canvas. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Just found that piece of code somewhere which helps in adjusting the app to work different screen sizes.